# EXtjs Grid Filters, filter specific rows

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

I am a new user of Extjs library, I created a grid successfully and it works just fine, now I want to use Ext.grid.GridFilters to add filtering to my grid, however when I add the filtering it works, but it filters all rows but I want to exclude last 3 rows from filtering.

How can I filter just specified rows?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm affraid you won't find any built-in resources that will help you do that right away, so you'll probably need to create your own solution. I recommend you take a look at remote filtering; maybe that's the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

u could use a function to filter the grid and exclude to apply it when u reach a row with a specific idkey or specific field value.

like ext js documentation

```
var longNameFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
filterFn: function(item) {
    return item.name.length > 4;
}});
```